# Android - Get and Set Mock Location (as system app) without enabling it in settings

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to create an Android App which is able to get and set Mock Location, without enabling Mock Location in Developer Settings. 
I have been able to achieve that to an extent, using different questions over SO, but am now stuck over the issue that it only changes the location once, and not after that.
My Code:

```
//onCreate()
 mLocationManager =  (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    gps  = new GPSTracker(this);


 public void updateCoordinates(DIRECTIONS direction ) // DIRECTIONS is an enum
{

        double tempLatitude, tempLongitude;

    tempLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
    tempLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
    if(direction == DIRECTIONS.UP)
    {
        tempLatitude = gps.getLatitude() + 1;
        tempLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
    }
    if(direction == DIRECTIONS.DOWN)
    {
        tempLatitude = gps.getLatitude() - 1;
        tempLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
    }
    if(direction == DIRECTIONS.LEFT)
    {
       tempLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
        tempLongitude = gps.getLongitude() + 1;
    }
    if(direction == DIRECTIONS.RIGHT)
    {
        tempLatitude = gps.getLatitude() - 1;
        tempLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
    }
    Location tempLocation = new Location(provider);
   tempLocation.setLatitude(tempLatitude);
   tempLocation.setLongitude(tempLongitude);

    tempLocation.setAccuracy(500);
    tempLocation.setAltitude(0D);
    tempLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    tempLocation.setBearing(0F);
   tempLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    setCoordinates(tempLocation);
}


enum DIRECTIONS
{
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}


public void getCoordinates(View v)
{

    String latitude, longitude;
    gps.getLocation();

    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        latitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
        coordinates.setText(latitude + "," + longitude);
    }
    else if(!gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        coordinates.setText("ERROR");
    }

}

public void initializeGPS(boolean state)   //Used to add and remove provider in onCreate() and onDestroy()
{

    int value = setMockLocationSettings();

    try{
    if(state)
    {
         mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(provider);
         mLocationManager.addTestProvider(provider, false, true, false, false, true, true, false, 0, 5);
         mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(provider, true);
         mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, gps.getLocation());
    }
        if(!state)
        {

            mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false);
            mLocationManager.clearTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            mLocationManager.clearTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        }
}
catch (Exception e) {}
finally {
    restoreMockLocationSettings(value);
}

}
public void setCoordinates(Location fake_location)
{


    int value = setMockLocationSettings();//toggle ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION on

    try {
        mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, fake_location);

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        restoreMockLocationSettings(value);//toggle ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION off
    }
}
private int setMockLocationSettings() {
    int value = 1;
    try {
        value = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION);
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}

private void restoreMockLocationSettings(int restore_value) {
    try {
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, restore_value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To get the GPS Coordinates, I use a class named GPSTracker

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

I guess the problem is with the provider I set, because it used to give a lot of errors, before I added the initializeGPS()

Comment: Did you test this out in marshmallow?

Comment: No, I tried it in Lollipop

Comment: My tests shows that this does not work anymore in marshmallow. Lollipop and below works fine.  Can you confirm on 6.0?

Comment: My tests on lollipop currently show that it only is able to change once, after that it has no effect. My best guess would be the provider is causing some conflict